# How are ubuntu iso's built?

Tags: live-cd

I wanted to try making a custom iso with some extra packages. Though it is possible to do this manually (by editing a standard iso) using various tools, I want to do this automatically from the repositories, the same way the daily builds of the ubuntu iso is made.

How does the ubuntu server do it/ how can I reproduce it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: I read that page.. it talks of modifying an existing ISO. I was more interested in making an ISO from scratch like how the ubuntu cdimage servers make theirs.

Comment: There is a [thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=352460) which describes a full process.